# Buscar maior campo em uma tabela com Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou utilizando o Laravel para uma API

No meu BD tenho uma tabela chamada `tbmanifestacao` e nesta tabela tenho uma coluna chamada `nrmanifestacao`

Gostaria de no meu **controller** retornar o maior `nrmanifestacao`

Tentei assim:

```
$nr = DB::select('select MAX(nrmanifestacao) from tbmanifestacao', [1]);
```

Mas não funcionou, além dq sei que não é o correto utilizar o SQL, mas sim o **Eloquent**

Como poderia fazer essa busca?

Comment: Uma maneira de fazer: `DB::table('tbmanifestacao')->max('nrmanifestacao');`

Comment: Provavelmente você deve possuir um model de `tbmanifestacao`, então poderia fazer usando eloquent: `seuModel::max('nrmanifestacao');`

Comment: @MarceloBoni esse segundo funcionou

Comment: @MarceloBoni o primeiro agora tbm, mas tive que por `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`